# How to plot circle with Maxima?

Tags: graphing-functions, maxima-software

I cannot get equitation plotted

Expression:

```
f1: (x^2) + (y^2) = 9;
```

I try this command:

```
wxplot2d(f1, [x, -5, 5], [y, -5, 5]);
```

And it gives:

```
plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in plotting range.
plot2d: nothing to plot.
```

What is correct way to plot such expressions?

Comment: You have to solve for a variable to plot. As you have it now, $f1$ is not an equation but is a relation. It is trying all $x,y$ and getting a lot of 'False', it won't know to just take the $(x,y)$ that satisfy that equation. Try solving for just one of the variables.

Comment: I will do that with an implicit plot
$$\begin{align}
& \text{load(draw);}\\
& \text{draw2d(implicit(x^2+y^2-9,x,-4,4,y,-4,4));}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @achillehui can you please covert your last comment to answer, it seems to be best answer I got so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comment turned answer by request. One can plot the circle as an implicit plot.
$$
\begin{align}
& \text{load(draw);}\\
& \text{draw2d(implicit(x^2+y^2-9,x,-4,4,y,-4,4));}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 methods to draw circle with radius = 3 and centered at the origin :

1. load(draw); draw2d(polar(3,theta,0,2*%pi));
2. [load(draw); draw2d(ellipse (0, 0, 3, 3, 0,360)](http://riotorto.users.sourceforge.net/Maxima/gnuplot/ellipse/index.html)
3. plot2d ([parametric, 3*cos(t), 3*sin(t), [t,-%pi,%pi],[nticks,80]], [x, -4, 4])$
4. load(implicit_plot);
   z:x+y*%i;
   implicit_plot (abs(z) = 3, [x, -4, 4], [y, -4, 4]);

Your function is implicit and multivalued

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I ended with qdraw:

```
(load(draw), load(qdraw));
f1: (x^2) + (y^2) = 9;
qdraw(imp(f1, x, -4, 4, y, -4, 4));
```